# SSRS 2016 running slow with blocking

Tags: sql-server-2016, reporting, ssrs-2016

SSRS 2016 - Standard Default Settings.
Work Horse for Reporting.  Some large reports can run 5 hours+.
Most reports cannot be optimized/tuned - 3rd party vendor.

On occasion noticed procs "WriteLockSession,CreateChunkSegment,ReadChunkSegment" in multiple sessions with millions of reads and writes , and at times Blocking.

Noticed these table have over 400k records: SegmentedChunk, ChunkSegmentMapping and Segment. Is there a standard process to clean up these tables (unused data) ,or check these tables for orphan records?  Does 400k sound high (like a problem), have other SSRS instances with much lower counts.

Restarted SSRS - no change.
Shrink db - no change.
Index optimization and update stats - regular maintenance.

Comment: "*Most reports cannot be optimized/tuned - 3rd party vendor*" - Welp that's unfortunate, because that's likely where the problem lies and what the correct solution would be - poorly designed reports. If there's data that can be removed to reduce the number of rows to be operated on and presented then that can help, but only you can decide that.

Comment: Of course it's all dependent on the specs (RAM, CPU, etc.) of the server, but 400k rows is not really all that many in the scheme of things.  You say things can't be optimised/tuned in the reports - do you mean that you, yourself, have no access to amend anything, or the vendor says you can't change anything?  Do you have the ability to run SQL Profiler, and really get to the statement/s that are likely causing issues?

Comment: Thanks for your response J.D.  and Craig.   SQL server specs are good( 8 - 2.0 GHz CPU and 56 GB memory) .  Vendors accepts our feedback (sometimes) when we send info on slow/long running reports.   My main concern was the size of these tables and was wondering if we needed to investigate them further, want to eliminate what I can on our end.

Comment: @jay No problem. Yea your specs are solid. Unfortunately performance issues are likely a software issue, and fixing the software usually results in the best returns on performance. Generally it's a mix of the following 3 software things: query issue, index issue, database design / architectural issue. You can run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) while one of the slow reports are running to get a live query plan and the wait stars to reveal some clues on why it's slow. Definitely helpful information to pass along to the vendor. FWIW, 400k rows is not much generally.